# Filing not opening within program

Tags: python

So I've typed out my full code and it will run but it won't read from the file that I have in the program

```
def main():
    #Variables
    num_upper = 0
    num_lower = 0
    num_space = 0
    num_digits = 0
    data = ''

    #Opening text.txt for reading
    infile = open('text.txt', 'r')

    #Read data from file
    data = infile.read()
    
    #Ste through each character in the file
    #Determine the varying variables and keep a total of each
    for ch in infile:
        if ch.isupper():
            num_upper = num_upper + 1
        if ch.islower():
            num_lower = num_lower + 1
        if ch.isdigit():
            num_digits = num_digits + 1
        if ch.isspace():
            num_space = num_space + 1

    #Close file
    infile.close()

    #Display totals
    print('The number of uppercase letters in the file:', num_upper)
    print('The number of lowercase letters in the file:', num_lower)
    print('The number of digits in the file:', num_digits)
    print('The number of whitespace in the file:', num_space)

#calling main
main()
```

I'm pretty sure that my issue is from "infile" and "data" but I'm not sure how to improve it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: At first glance it looks like `for ch in infile:` should be `for ch in data:`.

Comment: That was it. Appreciate it man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over file stream which is `infile`, try iterate over `data`.

```
for ch in data:
    ...
    ...
```

You can use `with` statement with `open`. It provides closing stream after `with` block.

Also, why are you check character 4 times? Try use `elif` to improve performance.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    for ch in data:
        if ch.isspace():
            num_space += 1
        elif ch.isdigit():
            num_digits += 1
        elif ch.isupper():
            num_upper += 1
        elif ch.islower():
            num_lower += 1
```